# Select date ranges with NULL in "toDate"

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
PriceId PriceType  FromDate   ToDate         Price  ElementId
1           F      2014-01-01  NULL          0.00900      1
3           F      2014-01-01  2014-02-01    0.31470      4
4           F      2014-01-01  NULL        432.00000      3
6           F      2014-02-01  NULL          0.30950      4
7           F      2014-02-01  NULL          0.28990      2
```

The input is ElementID = 4, a fromDate and a toDate

I want all prices for an element where the from and todate are between the input period.
The toDate are to, but not including.

So, 2014-01-28 to 2014-03-01 should return record 3 & 6
2014-01-28 to 2014-02-01 should only return record 3.
2014-02-07 to 2014-03-01 should return record 6.

Can anyone help me complete the WHERE clause:

```
 WHERE ElementId = 4 AND...
```

TIA...

-- 
Dag Sunde.

Comment: HI Welcome to SO! i hope you enjoy the site. anyway what you ask its a basic date comparison: please read this [mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what the significance of a NULL `ToDate` is intended to be. I'll assume it means 'ongoing' or, basically , `NOW()`.

In that case, you need

```
  WHERE whatever
    AND FromDate >= ?starting
    AND IFNULL(ToDate, NOW()) < ?ending
```

This will work correctly as long as your FromDate values are always in the past and before your `ToDate` values, and your `?starting` parameters are before your `?ending`.

There may be a serious efficiency problem with this design. It's hard to use indexes to search for null values.

Comment: Pro tip: It's helpful in database design to be conceptually clear about the meaning of such things as NULL values. Often good searching and processing logic flows naturally from design clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
fromDate <= :yourMaxDateParameterHere and ( ToDate >= :yourMinDateParameterHere or ToDate is null )
```

Comment: Thisone worked, when i Changed fromdate <= to fromdate <...
the maxDate is to, but not including...

Thanks a lot guys!!! Much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Get some sleep and work on it tomorrow; '2014-01-28' as a @FromDate ( First parameter ) is between the FromDate of records 3 ( greater than '2014-01-01' ) and 6 ( less than '2014-02-01' ).

You probably want to consider the four following conditions:

- Your `FromDate` ( Column value ) needs to be less than your `ToDate` ( Column value ). - *Check*
- Your `@FromDate` ( variable / input ) needs to be less than your `@ToDate` ( variable / input ). - *Check*
- Your `FromDate` needs to be `[ between )` your `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`. - *To Do*
- Your `ToDate` needs to be `[ between )` your `@FromDate` and `@ToDate`, or `NULL`. - *To Do*

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50075e/10) is an example of your problem.  I've opted to use `OR` in this case to keep the query [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) - the trailing explains show the length of the key of the indexes I added used in the different ways to write the query - only the former uses the whole thing.

Effectively, the query is as follows:

```
SELECT  PriceID, PriceType, FromDate, 
        ToDate, Price, ElementID
FROM    Price
WHERE   ElementID = @ElementID

    -- AND FromDate < ToDate -- First condition, bad record

    -- AND @FromDate < @ToDate -- Second condition, bad input

    AND FromDate >= @FromDate -- third condition, between "[" ( inclusive )
    AND FromDate < @ToDate    -- and between ")" ( exclusive )

    AND (   ToDate IS NULL
        OR  ToDate >= @FromDate ) -- forth condition, between "["
    AND (   ToDate IS NULL
        OR  ToDate < @ToDate );   -- and between ")".
```